# How to get Call Back from ViewModel to View in Android

Tags: android, mvvm

I have ViewModel

```
  class MyViewModel extends BaseViewModel{
     public void foo(){
      // some code or return some boolean
      }
    }
```

View Class

```
    class MyView extends View{
    private MyViewModel myviewmodel;
        public void bindTo(MyViewModel viewModel) {
    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    context = viewModel.getContext();
    validateView();
    requestLayout();
}
private validateView(){

//some code
}


    }
```

this bind view method bind with adapter
I want to get call back in Myview class when ever i will validateView will call please suggest me how get call back from Viewmodel method to View in android.

Answer (score 1):

it is best practice to use live data for communicating from viewmodel to your view.

```
class MyViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> state = new MutableLiveData<Boolean>;

    public LiveData<Boolean> getState() {
        return state;
    }
    

    public void foo() {
        //bool = value returned of your work 
        state.setValue(bool);
    } }


class Myview extends View {

    public void onCreate() {
         viewmodel.getState().observe(this, observer); // 'this' is life cycle owner

    }

    final Observer<Boolean> observer = new Observer<Boolean>() {
           @Override
           public void onChanged(@Nullable final Boolean state) {
               // do your work with returned value
           }
    }; }
```

for more details refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#java)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Me if i wrong

- first you need to make interface class

```
public interface ViewModelCallback {
    void returnCallBack(Boolean mBoolean);
}
```

- then your View class implements that interface class & Override that method

```
class MyView extends View implements ViewModelCallback

 @Override
    public void returnCallBack(Boolean mBoolean) {
        //here you will retrieve callback
       // Do Something
    }
```

- Next you just pass a value from your view model

```
class MyViewModel {
    private ViewModelCallback myViewCallBack;

    public void foo() {
        Boolean yourReturnValue = false;
        myViewCallBack.returnCallBack(yourReturnValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK wait let me check your solution @koridor thanx

Comment: i am not getting call back  using your give solution @koridor

Comment: check if your foo method is called

Comment: In this way, isn't the ViewModel is retaining an instance of the view, which shouldn't be done due to ViewModel survives to configuration changes? I'm also looking for a solution to this. The same problem is mentioned on the comments of this post https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-communication-between-viewmodel-and-view-ce14805d72bf